# onSnapshot load multiple Firebase collections in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new React and still learning about UseEffect. I have a NextJS app where I am getting a single Firebase collection ('documents') using UseEffect on loading. I would like to get a second collection as well ('documentTypes'). Would I put the second collection query in the same UseEffect hook? I have tried but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const collectionRef = collection(db, 'documents');

        const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('date'));

        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot => {
            setDocuments(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);
```

I have thought that maybe I should place both of these collections into a single collection but I can't seem to figure out how to load subcollections, and I am not sure if that would be a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Got it to work:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const documents = collection(db, 'documents');
        const q = query(documents, orderBy('date'));

        onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot => {
            setDocuments(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        });

        const documentTypes = collection(db, 'documentTypes');
        const qu = query(documentTypes, orderBy('name'));

        onSnapshot(qu, querySnapshot => {
            setDocumentTypes(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        });

        return;
    }, []);
```

Not sure it is the best way to do it, but it seems to work.